# How to sort ng-repeat by two parameters and array?

Tags: angularjs

In my template I use `ng-repeat="obj in list"`.

Where `list` is object:

```
0: {
  status : "active",
  category : "animal"
}
...
```

Also by default I have `$scope.filter = {}`

When I handle click: I fill this `$scope.filter`:

```
$scope.filter["categories"].push("animal");
$scope.filter["categories"].push("human");
```

How to make that `filter` in `ng-repeat` will work with array `$scope.filter["categories"]` and will find elements where `category` is corresponding `$scope.filter["categories"]`?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to write your own custom filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have custom filter.

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {

      return function(arrList, arrKeywords) {

          var arrFilterList = [];

          angular.forEach(arrList,function(oneVal,key){

              if(arrKeywords.indexOf(oneVal)){
                arrFilterList.push(oneVal);  
              }
          })

          return arrFilterList;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

create a custom filter like this

```
angular.module("app",[])
.filter('sam',function(){
  return function(item, arr){
    return arr.find(function(obj){ 
      return obj === item;
    })
  }
})
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.filter('sam',function(){
  return function(item, arr){
    return arr.find(function(obj){ 
      return obj === item;
    })
  }
})
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.list = [{
  status : "active",
  category : "animal"
},{
  status : "active",
  category : "human"
},{
  status : "active",
  category : "bird"
}]

$scope.filter = {"categories":[]}

$scope.filter["categories"].push("animal");
$scope.filter["categories"].push("human");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="obj in list ">
{{obj.category | sam : filter.categories}}
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why not a filter at the collection level (so it can be applied at `ng-repeat`)?

Comment: because then the filter pass the whole list array instead of an object and need a another additional loop to filter the relevant value

Comment: Angular will filter before the `ng-repeat` loop so I'm not sure that the idea of "another additional loop" is correct here. I would think best practice would be to filter at the collection level.